# Instrumenting constructors in Javassist using insertAfter

Tags: javassist

I am trying to instrument constructors to print out something when they are called. I do this by using [insertAfter](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtBehavior.html#insertAfter(java.lang.String)). I also wanted to print out the object reference. I tried using `$_` but that was just set to 0. Is printing out the object reference of the newly newed object possible?

Comment: Can we see some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended finding a solution to what i wanted. It consisted of using an [ExprEditor](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/expr/ExprEditor.html) like this:

```
public CtClass instrumentMethods() throws CannotCompileException, IOException {
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    cp.insertClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(loader));
    CtClass ctKlazz = cp.makeClass(instream);

    CtMethod[] methods = ctKlazz.getMethods();
    for (CtMethod method : methods) {
        final CtBehavior method = methods[ind];
        method.instrument(
            new ExprEditor() {
                // Instrument new expressions:
                public void edit(NewExpr expr) throws CannotCompileException {
                    final int allocSiteId = getAllocSiteId(className, expr.indexOfBytecode());
                    expr.replace( "{ $_ = $proceed($$); someCodeHere($_); }");
                }
            }
        );
        method.insertBefore("{ someInstrumentationAtStart(); }");
    }

    return ctKlazz;
}
```